# How to share data between two computer connected through the local wireless

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have a few computers connected to the same wireless router. What is the best/easiest way to share data among them. I am sick and tired of using AIM to copy data from one computer to another.

They are all Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to configure file sharing in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040), and [File and Printer Sharing in Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727037.aspx)